# TYPO3 backend routes

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I'm experiencing a strange problem with the backend UI.

Some extensions (Extension Builder and Luxletter) are not building the links correctly. As a result I can't change pages in the backend of the respective extension.

Example: Luxletter will load when clicked on the side nav (loads the dashboard) but will not change to newsletter page.

Expected link: `https://webserver.rado/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmodule%2Flux%2FLuxletterLuxletter&token=16e398a5467b3415e5c24cfff2de5df8595e74ef&tx_luxletter_lux_luxletterluxletter%5Baction%5D=list&tx_luxletter_lux_luxletterluxletter%5Bcontroller%5D=Newsletter`

Actual link: `http://webserver.rado/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmodule%2Flux%2FLuxletterLuxletter&token=84b471f164850080501feb0eb6b854d058d1c6fb&tx__%5Baction%5D=list&tx__%5Bcontroller%5D=Newsletter`

BE Modules Variables seem to have the correct values. No problem detected from TYPO3 logs.

TYPO3 10.4.37, luxletter 17.8.0, Extension Builder 10.0.5

I tried different versions of the extensions. No luck.

Comment: "Some extensions" sounds somewhat like a non-systematic problem. This makes me think of (faulty/outdated) cache entries or the like. Have you already cleared caches via the install tool?

Comment: I did. I also tried droping the extension tables and generated them again also without luck. I am looking the layouts but they seem alrignt. Lux is using the <f:link.action> and extension builder <f:be.menus.ActionMenu>